# How to stop the NetworkActivity on a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I load some content on my UIWebview ,and when the UIWebView load finish the content of a URL such as "http://www.google.com", but the network NetworkActivityIndicator didn't stop,any suggestion?

I found somebody use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES],but I think this is just to hidden the NetworkActivityIndicator ,in fact it does't stop,is that right??

Now what I want is really to stop the NetworkActivityIndicator ,how to accomplish it??

Answer (score 4):

In your UIWebView delegate:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Remove any other calls to -setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible in this delegate.'

If you haven't already assigned a delegate for this UIWebView, then do so as follows:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

This of course assumes you are inside a UIViewController and that `self.view` exists, so change as needed.

Comment: Does't the network Interaction really  stop? what I want is to stop the network interaction....

Comment: That's not what you said you wanted to stop in your original post. If that's the case, then call the -stopLoading method on the webview as so: `[webView stopLoading];`.

Comment: It is that network Activity Indicator roate all the time .I want to stop the rotation,can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO` is the only way to stop the rotation, and it is controlled by *your* app, so it is likely you have a bug in your code.

Comment: setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO  Can this method to stop the network?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the network load, it's just a spinner you can show when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

@McGrady:Try this..

`- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidfinishLoad");
    [activity  stopAnimating];
}`

Here activity is your activityindicator name
Hope this help you..

Regards

Renuga